# Creating a variable that appends together strings

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a data frame like so:

| moves | game_id |
| --- | --- |
| e2e4 | 1 |
| cfc8 | 1 |
| g6e4 | 1 |
| f6g8 | 2 |
| f8g5 | 2 |
| e2e4 | 3 |
| d8b6 | 3 |
| h7a3 | 3 |

I want to create a column which appends each previous string in 'moves' to a list that grows, but restarts for the next 'game_id'.

So that I create a table like so:

| moves | game_id | move_list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e2e4 | 1 | e2e4 |
| cfc8 | 1 | e2e4 cfc8 |
| g6e4 | 1 | e2e4 cfc8 g6e4 |
| f6g8 | 2 | f6g8 |
| f8g5 | 2 | f6g8 f8g5 |
| e2e4 | 3 | e2e4 |
| d8b6 | 3 | e2e4 d8b6 |
| h7a3 | 3 | e2e4 d8b6 h7a3 |

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `accumulate` after grouping

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
 group_by(game_id) %>%
  mutate(move_list  = accumulate(moves, str_c, sep = " ")) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  moves game_id move_list     
  <chr>   <int> <chr>         
1 e2e4        1 e2e4          
2 cfc8        1 e2e4 cfc8     
3 g6e4        1 e2e4 cfc8 g6e4
4 f6g8        2 f6g8          
5 f8g5        2 f6g8 f8g5     
6 e2e4        3 e2e4          
7 d8b6        3 e2e4 d8b6     
8 h7a3        3 e2e4 d8b6 h7a3
```

---

If the output should be a `list` column, use `c/append` instead of `paste`ing

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(game_id) %>% 
  mutate(move_list  = accumulate(moves,  c)) %>% 
  ungroup
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  moves game_id move_list
  <chr>   <int> <list>   
1 e2e4        1 <chr [1]>
2 cfc8        1 <chr [2]>
3 g6e4        1 <chr [3]>
4 f6g8        2 <chr [1]>
5 f8g5        2 <chr [2]>
6 e2e4        3 <chr [1]>
7 d8b6        3 <chr [2]>
8 h7a3        3 <chr [3]>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(moves = c("e2e4", "cfc8", "g6e4", "f6g8", "f8g5", 
"e2e4", "d8b6", "h7a3"), game_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `ave` + `Reduce`

```
transform(
  df,
  move_list = ave(
    moves,
    game_id,
    FUN = function(x) Reduce(paste, x, accumulate = TRUE)
  )
)
```

gives

```
  moves game_id      move_list
1  e2e4       1           e2e4
2  cfc8       1      e2e4 cfc8
3  g6e4       1 e2e4 cfc8 g6e4
4  f6g8       2           f6g8
5  f8g5       2      f6g8 f8g5
6  e2e4       3           e2e4
7  d8b6       3      e2e4 d8b6
8  h7a3       3 e2e4 d8b6 h7a3
```